# Trainer already configured error - Google TFT (Temporal Fusion Transformer)

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I'm following [this](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/stallion.html) example on demand forecasting, and when trying to run the trainer, I get the error found further down. I'm not sure where to remove the BatchSizeFinder. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

```
res = trainer.tuner.lr_find(
    tft,
    train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
    max_lr=10.0,
    min_lr=1e-6,
)
```

Error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/Users/gseite/Development/production_forecasting/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/tuner/tuning.py", line 253, in lr_find
    _check_tuner_configuration(self.trainer, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, dataloaders, method)
  File "/Users/gseite/Development/production_forecasting/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/tuner/tuning.py", line 300, in _check_tuner_configuration
    raise MisconfigurationException(
lightning_lite.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: Trainer is already configured with a `BatchSizeFinder` callback. Please remove it if you want to use tuner
```

Tried running as per example, but got an error instead.